# Multiple dropdownlist in asp.net mvc to actionresult

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, drop-down-menu

I am using jquery choose multiple dropdownlist.

I have multiple values from selected dropdownlist.

**Html:**

```
    @using (Html.BeginForm()) {
    <div class="editor-field" style="width:150px;">

    @Html.DropDownList("UserRole", null, new { @class = "chosen-select",@multiple="multiple",@placeholder="Lütfen Rol Seçiniz",@style="width:250px;"})

    </div>

    <input type="submit" value="Create" />
}
```

When i click to create button button submits to below actionresult

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult AddUser(List<UserRole> UserRole) 
{
return view();
}
```

UserRole is always null when i post it

**UserRole Class properties below**

```
public int UserRoleID { get; set; }
public Nullable<int> FirmUserID { get; set; }
public Nullable<int> RoleID { get; set; }
```

Where i miss how can i get selected all values in multiple dropdownlist ?

Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: A multiple select posts back an array of value types, but you trying to bind to a collection of complex types.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to use a ListBox to get the behavior you desire, instead of a dropdown list. The ListBox can accept an array of selected roles, along with a MultiSelectList to display the selected items.

I would also recommend using a view model, instead of relying upon the ViewBag for handing your view state. See [CloneMatching](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14218989/best-way-to-clone-properties-of-disparate-objects) for the extension method.

```
    @model UserRoleViewModel
    ...
    <div>
        <div class="editor-label">
            User Roles<br />(Ctrl-click for multiple)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.ListBoxFor(model => model.SelectedRoles,new MultiSelectList(model.AvailableRoles,"Id","Description",Model.SelectedRoles))
        </div>        
    </div>
```

UserRoleViewModel:

```
 public class UserRoleViewModel {
     public User { get; set; }

     public List<int> SelectedRoles { get; set; }
     public List<Role> AvailableRoles { get; set; }
 }
```

UserRoleController:

```
 public ActionResult Edit(int id) {
     var user = MyDbContext.Users.Find(id);
     var model = new Model {
         User = user;
         SelectedRoles = user.UserRoles.Select(userRole => userRole.Role.Id).ToList();
         AvailableRoles = MyDb.Context.Roles.ToList();
     };
     return View(model);
 }

 [HttpPost]
 public ActionResult Edit(UserRoleViewModel model) {
     if (ModelState.IsValid) {
         var user = MyDbContext.Users.Find(id).CloneMatching(model.User);
         user.UserRoles.Clear();
         MyDbContext.SaveChanges();

         foreach( var roleId in model.SelectedRoles) {
             users.UserRoles.Add(new UserRole {
                 UserId = user.Id,
                 RoleId = roleId
             });
         }
         MyDbContext.SaveChanges();
         return RedirectToAction("Index");
     }        
     return View(model);
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

in your scenario add the listbox like this `@Html.ListBox("UserRole", null, new { @class = "chosen-select",@multiple="multiple",@placeholder="Lütfen Rol Seçiniz",@style="width:250px;"})`  so you find the result.

Comment: becuase list return multi value and dropdown return only single value .